# Derivative of Gauss' Pi Function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, factorial

Famous mathematician and scientist [Carl Gauss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss) developed the Pi function

$$\Pi(x)=\int_{t=0}^\infty t^x e^{-t}\,dt$$

which has the property that
$$\Pi(n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(k\right)=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n=n!$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. In other words, the Pi function generalizes the factorial operator to the real numbers (and complex numbers also).

Wikipedia says the factorial function grows faster than all exponential functions (and therefore faster than all polynomial functions) but not as fast as hyper-exponential functions, otherwise known as [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) or towering. Well, I would like to know exactly how fast it grows.

**What is the rate of growth of the Pi function?**

$$\Pi^{\prime}(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{t=0}^\infty t^x e^{-t}\,dt$$

Is the [FTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) applicable here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $\Pi$ function is one of my favourites.  Using [differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign),

$$\Pi'(x)=\frac{\text d}{\text dx}\int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t}\,\text dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial }{\partial x}t^x e^{-t}\,\text dt = \int_0^\infty t^{x}e^{-t}\log t\,\text dt \tag{1} = \Pi(x) \Psi (x+1)$$

where $\Psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Repeated differentiation yields

$$\Pi^{(n)}(x)=\int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t}\log^n t \,\text dt \tag{2}$$

---

An interesting special case of $(1)$ can be found by letting $x = 0$:

$$\Pi'(0) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}\log t\, \text dt = -\gamma = -0.577216\dots$$

where $\displaystyle \gamma = \lim_{n \to\infty} 1+\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} - \log n\;\;$ is [Euler's Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Answer (score 1):

Recall that, if you define
$$
\Gamma (z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}\, dt,
$$
there results (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Alternative_definitions))
$$
\Pi(z)=\Gamma (z+1)=z \Gamma (z),
$$
and since
$$
\frac{d}{dz}\Gamma (z)= \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t} \log t \, dt,
$$
you deduce that
$$
\frac{d}{dz}\Pi (z) = \Gamma (z) + z \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t} \log t \, dt.
$$

Comment: Please explain line 3.

Comment: Just differentiate under the integral sign.

Comment: Got it. If you can directly differentiate $\Gamma$ then is it possible to directly differentiate $\Pi$ without putting it in terms of $\Gamma$?

Comment: Of course. I proposed this approach since the Gamma function is usually well-known.